# Dynamic casting in apex

Tags: apex, knowledge, dynamic-apex

I'm not sure how to solve the following:

```
public String dummy(SObject[] obj) {
   obj.getsomething();
}
```

`obj` can be two different objects (both of them implement a method name `getsomething`).

The name of the objects are only known on runtime.

I've tried the following:

```
public String dummy(SObject[] obj) {
   ((getObjectName())obj).getsomething();
}
```

But It's not possible in apex.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

Actually it is SObject - As I switched the KnowledgeArticle to lightning the SObject can be (KnowledgeArticleVersion or Knowledge_Kav).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a separate answer for `SObject`, as it is a very different question and therefore the answer is quite different. To reiterate:

> Please note that SObject and Object are very different types. And adding [] at the end of your type definition makes it a List, again a huge difference.

Anyway, if your method accepts `List<SObject>` and you want dynamic logic based on that, you should read up on **[Dynamic Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic.htm)**. A couple methods will be useful for you here:

- `List<SObject>.getSObjectType()`
- `SObject.get(String field)`

You may want a map of `SObjectType` to field. One way that might work:

```
static Map<SObjectType, SObjectField> fieldsToCheck = new Map<SObjectType, SObjectField>
{
    MyObject__c.sObjectType => MyObject__c.SomeField__c,
    OtherObject__c.sObjectType => OtherObject__c.OtherField__c
};

public static void doStuff(List<SObject> records)
{
    if (record == null) { /* figure out if/how to handle null inputs */ }

    SObjectField field = fieldsToCheck.get(records.getSObjectType());
    if (field == null) { /* figure out how to handle unsupported input */ }

    for (SObject record : records)
    {
        Object value = record.get(field);
        // do stuff with value
    }
}
```

A couple notes on nomenclature:

- An *object* is a type definition. It can be either a primitive or a standard/custom class.
- An *SObject* is a table in your database.
- An *instance* is a construction of either of the above.
- A *record* is an instance of an SObject.

Try to keep these in mind when naming your variables.

Answer (score 8):

Please note that `SObject` and `Object` are very different types. And adding `[]` at the end of your type definition makes it a `List`, again a huge difference.

The text of your post indicates you meant `Object`, so I will answer as if that's the case.

Regardless, the key here is that if you have a few different types you want to guarantee all implement a specific method, use an `interface`.

```
interface Foo
{
    void getSomething();
}
```

Then, assuming you know your `Object` collection passed in contains implementations of this interface, you would call:

```
for (Object instance : collection)
{
    Foo implementation = (Foo)instance;
    implementation.getSomething();
}
```

Make sure to add the `implements` keyword to your other classes:

```
public class Bar implements Foo
{
    public void getSomething() { /*implementation*/ }
}
```

You can read much more about how interfaces work **[in the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_interfaces.htm)**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually it is SObject - As I switched the KnoledgeArticle to lightning the SObject can be (KnowledgeArticleVersion or Knowledge_Kav)

Comment: Yeah @omri I added a separate answer that addresses the other interpretation of your question.

Answer (score 4):

Apex doesn't really have much in the way of reflection or introspection.

While we do have the [Type class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_type.htm) (which has the `forName()` method), you still need to know the name of the object at compile time to be able to really make use of it.

`forName()` takes a string, and you can call `newInstance()` to get an instance of the type that was returned by `forName()`, but `newInstance()` returns a generic `object`...which you won't be able to call any methods on without downcasting to a more specialized type (which is the thing we're trying to avoid knowing at compile-time in the first place).

Instead of trying to cast to a specific class, this sounds like a situation where you should make use of an `interface` instead.

The idea is that the interface tells you which methods are available, what their return type is, and the parameters that need to be passed to each method.

```
public interface IMyInterface{
    Integer doSomeMath(Integer arg1, Integer arg2);
}
```

Other classes can then *implement* that interface

```
// 'implements <interface name>' is the syntax here that you add to the class
//   definition
public class MyClass implements IMyInterface{

    // Implementing an interface means that you need to "implement" all of
    //   the methods specified by that interface
    public Integer doSomeMath(Integer arg1, Integer arg2){
        return arg1 + arg2;
    }
}

public class MyOtherClass implements IMyInterface{

    // Other classes can have other implementations.
    // The point is that the method signature is the same
    public Integer doSomeMath(Integer arg1, Integer arg2){
        return arg1 * arg2;
    }
}
```

Part of the power of interfaces is that you can treat any class that implements an interface as if it were an instance of that type.

```
List<IMyInterface> interfaceList = new List<IMyInterface>();
// We can typecast both classes as IMyInterface
// More importantly, we can know about this interface type at compile-time
interfaceList.add((IMyInterface)new MyClass());
interfaceList.add((IMyInterface)new MyOtherClass());

// Now that they're the same "type", we can call the interface methods on them
//   without further casting.
for(IMyInterface implementation :interfaceList){
    system.debug(implementation.doSomeMath(2, 3));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually it is SObject - As I switched the KnoledgeArticle to lightning the SObject can be (KnowledgeArticleVersion or Knowledge_Kav)